# QGIS python plugin, segmentation fault, what can I do?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to write a python plugin to create an input file for an urban climate model out of three shape files. Unfortunatelly QGIS closes when I try to load the plugin. When I start QGIS from the Terminal (Ubuntu), I get "segmentation fault" when it happens. Thats all. Is there some way to prevent QGIS from crashing or another way to track down the error?

Comment: You can run it in a debugger like gdb and see where it crashes (if you have the symbols/a debug build). Also make sure your plugin has all the required basic data set.

Comment: have you checked with qgis-dev mailing list? The developers (while some of them are crawling the site) might be able to give you more assistance - or fix the issue if you stumbled into a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to the development mailing list, as suggested, and was told that it was very likely something with my signal definitions, that were located in a seperate dialogue classe. After moving them into the main classe no further crashes occured. Thanks!